# Apply style lines on email in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, email

I am making a PHP script to get information from a DB, and paint a table with all information filled up. Then it sends an email to the client.

My issue: I know that all mail clients ignore CSS scripts, so, I did the work to get all the styles directly to:

```
<label class="control-label" for="numero_cliente" style="-webkit-app-region:   no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(119, 119, 119);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-locale: en;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
& more the style tags
">N&uacute;mero de cliente: </label>
```

In the web browser, it worked perfectly but in Gmail it painted all the style:

```
<label class="control-label" for="numero_cliente" style="-webkit-app-regi..>
```

But Hotmail ignored it and it printed like it wants to.

Is there a way to make email clients read those lines or should I continue trying inline editor or writing them to all styles tags?

[Gmail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV9OB.png)

[hotmail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeLWy.png)

Comment: `<style="stuff here">` is not a valid tag. Could you post what you're actually sending?

Comment: already edited @Barmar

Comment: `all mail clients ignore CSS scripts` I don't thinks so, most do ignore external ones, why not put in into `<style></style>` tags in your email-body ?

Comment: Especially Gmail is completely rebuilding/interpreting your mailhtml... Just stick to old school inline style, tables and images...